# Once UIActionSheet dismissed, the screen became locked out

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

I dismissed the UIActionSheet , but the screen became locked out and unresponsive. The center became hightlighted and rest of edge area dimmed.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)menu didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0: 
            return;
        case 1: 
            return;
        case 2: 
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you tried to show a UIAlertView but the alert didn't actually appear. Did you do something like try to show an alert from a background thread?

Comment: It's an actionsheet, it showed up and dismissed. But after dismissed, the screen is frozen or locked out.

Comment: I suggested UIAlertView because that has the dimming effect you mentioned (where the center is bright but the sides are dim).

Comment: I don't need that dimming effect, its just a byproduct after I dismissed the actionsheet.

Comment: let me check if that's alerview that's causing the problem. I did used that before I used the action sheet.

Comment: I think issue is I have an UIAlertView popped up first and when I clicked Yes, Actionsheet will pop up next. After I dismissed the actionsheet then this issue came up.   So somehow bringing up both Alertview and Actionsheet got some conflict issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with UIActionSheet coming before UIAlertView disappears. I solved this problem by calling the action to present UIActionSheet after a delay of 0.3 seconds.